# Compare two static arrays

Tags: c++

I have an issue how to implement to compare two static arrays, ie.

```
string bufferNames[]={"apple","orange","banana","pomegranate","pear"};
string bufferPictures[] = {"apple.bmp","orange.bmp","banana.bmp","pomegranate.bmp","pear.bmp"};
```

Each item in the bufferNames presents the choice that to someone has been given, when the picture from the bufferPictures has been loaded onto the screen. So, if I for example get orange.bmp using rand() function that iterates through that list, how can I get the same one corresponding element orange and two other random not correct elements. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. If further breaking in of the problem is needed, just say it so.

Comment: It looks like a homework, I would say. Why not to tag it so?

Comment: It's not a homework, and since there is nowhere on the internet how to solve this, I came up here. @pmr Excellent proposal! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. The code makes use of the C++11 features. You will
need to adapt it, to pass it off as homework.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct Picture {
  std::string name, file;
  bool operator==(const Picture& x) const { return this->name == x.name && this->file == x.file; }
  bool operator!=(const Picture& x) const { return !(*this == x); }

};

int main()
{
  std::vector< Picture > pics = 
    {
      {"apple", "apple.bmp"},
      {"orange", "orange.bmp"},
      {"banana", "banana.bmp"},
      {"pear", "pear.bmp"},
    };

  // determined by random choice
  const Picture& choice = pics[0];

  std::vector< Picture > woChoice;
  std::copy_if(pics.begin(), pics.end(), std::back_inserter(woChoice), 
               [&choice](const Picture& x) {
                 return x != choice;
               });

  // random shuffle the remainder and pick the first
  // two. alternatively and for more efficience use std::random to
  // generate indices
  std::random_shuffle(woChoice.begin(), woChoice.end());
  std::cout << woChoice[0].name << std::endl;
  std::cout << woChoice[1].name << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nicely done! It is very useful to me and I hope all the others.

Comment: @DzekTrek I hate to complain about stuff like that. But so why don't you honor it with an upvote?

Comment: Not that it's likely to matter practically, but it's worth pointing out that this is remarkably inefficient in memory and CPU usage....

Comment: Sorry, I am not in able to vote your post up, since I am a toddler, don't have proper privileges to do so. But for the record, this solution is one of the finest.

Comment: @TonyDelroy Certainly but it was written with simplicity in mind. Although a better version wouldn't be so much harder to write, but I was to lazy to look up the new random facilities again.

Comment: @pmr , how is it possible for you to declare and initialise `std::vector< Picture > pics` at the same time? Did you use some special libriries for it or what? :)

Comment: @DzekTrek As I said: The code uses C++11 features. Initializer lists, `copy_if` and lambdas.

Comment: Nice! :) Also, if someone is interested, there are boost c++ libs to download just for this problem. Download it from here [http://www.boost.org/](http://www.boost.org/)

Answer (score 1):

> So, if I for example get orange.bmp using rand() function that iterates through that list, how can I get the same one corresponding element orange and two other random not correct elements.

If you use `rand()` to get a number (let's call it `x`) between 0 and 4 inclusive (based on there being 5 distinct values in the arrays), then you can use that number in both arrays to find the related word and image.

To get one other random incorrect element, you can call `rand()` in a loop until you get a value other than `x`.  Let's call it `y`.

To get another random incorrect elements, you can call `rand()` in a loop until you get a value other than `x` and `y`.

There are other ways to do this, but that's probably easiest to understand and implement.

Comment: Nice one, but I will have to change my point of the view on something like this `string Fruit[5][128] = {"apple","orange","banana","pomegranate","pear"};``string FruitPictures[5][128] = {"apple.bmp","orange.bmp","banana.bmp","pomegranate.bmp","pear.bmp"};`

Comment: @DzekTrek: "however" - getting one `rand()` for the correct answer IS what I suggested - the other suggested calls to `rand()` are for the incorrect elements :-). But it would be better to use `std::vector<string> fruits; fruits.push_back("apple"); fruits.push_back("orange");` etc, then `int x = rand() % fruits.size();`. Note that in your example you can say `fruits[x] + ".bmp"` to get the image filename, eliminating the second array/vector, though if the names weren't so consistently related that wouldn't work.

Comment: :) That's exactly what Gangnus told me to do so, and I have listened to him. AS for the vector size, it isn't bad idea at all, and will try to make something out of it. Thank you for this great effort. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. The names in arrays correspond to each other. So, if you need fruit
   number i, take bufferNames[i] and bufferPictures[i] in parallel way.
2. Ensure that names ARE parallel. Simply making the second array
   elements from the first array elements.
3. As for random in range `0..n-1` excluding elements number i,j (j>i), count it so:

   temp=random(n-3);
   k=(temp>=i?temp+1:temp);
   k=(k>=j?k+1:k);

And again, take bufferNames[k] and bufferPictures[k].

It is not simple, it is VERY simple.

Comment: This is what I needed! It is the best way for me to do so!

Comment: Thank you. I simply tried to make the answer more adequate to the question. Simple structures in question -> simple structures in answer. If it is the best for you, mark MINE answer as the best, please. You can move or turn on/off this green thingie at anytime. You can't upvote another correct answer yourself yet, but I shall do it right after sending this comment. The random is not so good there, but it works. And people are right - in future is you want to keep 2 sets in correspondence, make one set of pairs instead. It will save you from many errors.